# How to create a tooltip "copied to clipboard" upon clicking copy button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a tooltip "copied to clipboard" on clicking copy button. 
Below is the code,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        tool_tip_content: '',
    };
}

click = () => {
    this.input_ref.current.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    this.input_ref.current.blur();
    this.setState({ tool_tip_content: 'Copied to clipboard'});
};

<input readOnly ref={this.input_ref} value="hello"/>
<button onClick={this.click}>COPY</button>
    <span style={tooltipStyle}>Copied to Clipboard </span>
```

What i have tried is as below,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { on_copy_link_click: false }
}

click = () => {
    this.setState({ on_copy_link_click: true);
    this.input_ref.current.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
};
mouse_out = () => {
     this.setState({ tool_tip_content: ''});
};
<div className="tooltip">
    <input readOnly ref={this.input_ref} value="hello"/>
    <button onClick={this.click} onMouseOut={this.mouse_out}>COPY</button>
        <span className="tooltiptext">{this.state.tool_tip_content} </span>
</div>
```

Styling for the copylink tooltip is as below,

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The above code works as explained below,
1. on hovering on copylink button the tooltip with empty content is displayed
2. on clicking copylink button tooltip with content "copied to clipboard is displayed"
3. On mouseout tooltip is not displayed

**Expected result:** 
Only on clicking copylink button i want the tool tip to be displayed with content "copied to clipboard". on mouserover and mouseout tooltip shouldn't be displayed.

Can someone please help me with this.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can use conditional rendering...

```
   {this.state.tool_tip_content.length>0 && <span className="tooltiptext">{this.state.tool_tip_content} </span> }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use any library such as [react-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip),which makes your work easy.